# how to scape character "$" in puppet code?

Tags: string, puppet

Hi everyone I have a function in puppet code to replace "$" with "`$"
I have this string:

```
-nn=asdasdasd92asdHLaSbTT*psjyn$GTNXdZpLnQ3
```

so the result should be this one:

```
-nn=asdasdasd92asdHLaSbTT*psjyn`$GTNXdZpLnQ3
```

I need to scape the "$" because I use that string in powershell

i cant find what is wrong with my function its not doing the replace.

```
function profiles::scape_caracters (
  String            $password
) >> String {
  
  if $::facts['kernel'] == 'windows'{
    $scaped_password = regsubst($password, "\$", '\`$', 'G')
  }
  notify{"debug value: ${scaped_password}": }
  $scaped_password
}
```

Comment: You should probably change your first argument to a literal string `'$'` to avoid these escaping issues.

Comment: i try that, but it takes "$" as regular expression so when I do that it put "`$" at the end of the string because "$" in regex means the end of a string

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:

I needed to double backslash to escape the "$"

```
$scaped_password = regsubst($password, "\\$", '`$', 'G')
```